# Pattern for serialize/deserialize classes with enheritance in C++

Tags: c++, xml, design-patterns, serialization, deserialization

I have some class Hierarchy like:

```
class BaseDocument {
someValue_1
someValue_2
...
lot of values
}

class DerivedDocument1: public BaseDocument {
derived1Specific
}


class DerivedDocument2: public BaseDocument {
derived2Specific
}
```

Classes are stored in XML. I wish to serialize and deserialize these classes from/to XML. It is not so hard in Java or C#, but I use C++. Is there some pattern for "smart" serialization/deserialization ? Now I use 2 almost identical function which deserialize base part of documents and only difference between them is the last line with 'derived1Specific' or 'derived2Specific' values.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a library for this?
Like protobuff's or boost.serialization?

Comment: BTW, you may factorize your code for the `BaseDocument` part.

Comment: did you find any solution to this? I am in a similar situation.